# Firebase Console Notifications Sent > Play Store Install Base

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have recently switched out from GCM to FCM; and started using FCM Notifications Console to send out push notifications.

Everything works like a charm, Firebase even tells you how many people the notification was delivered to.

However, in my case the deliveries are nearly 1.7x the play store install base. Which just doesn't make sense; any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: That sounds unusual. Can you [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) with the same information, your project id and some details about the message you sent?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen have written a support ticket to Firebase. Thanks. 

Will let you know what they have to say.